# Fcitx "Extra key for trigger input method" changes back to default after restart

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, input-method, fcitx

Using Ubuntu 15.11. Configuring input using the 'Input Method Configuration' screen. Whenever I change "Extra key for trigger input method" it works for only that session. Once I restart the computer it goes back to the default value of "SHIFT Both" which annoying.

Is there a config file that is overwriting this every time I boot up?

Answer (score 1):

First you can use this command `fcitx-configtool` to open the fcitx config window,then you can change "Extra key for trigger input method" that you want.

Then you can `cd` into the fcitx config fold by `cd ~/.config/fcitx`
and  use `chmod 444 profile` to change the permission of the profile to read only ,so that no one can change back to default value.

You can restart you computer to see if it works.